# Browser support for Service Worker Task Scheduler

Tags: browser, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Does anybody know, whether the TaskScheduler API for service workers as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/task-scheduler/) is supported by any browser or when or whether it will be implemented in the future?

Unfortunately there is only very poor documentation about the features of service workers in regards to different browsers. So any references would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-task-scheduler-20150723/ contains the following note:

> This specification is being republished as a Working Group Note as an
>   indication that it not being progressed further as a Recommendation
>   track document.

I don't believe there's any expectation that the API, as described in that document, is going to be added to browsers.

Depending on what you're looking to do, some combination of the [Budget API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/budget-api), [Background Fetch API](https://github.com/WICG/background-fetch), and [Background Sync API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) might meet your use case, though they're not all widely supported, either.