# Angular 7 Start a function at 09:41 am

Tags: angular, firebase, time

Hi i use angular 7 and firebase. 
I just want to write a function that goes off every day at 9:41 am without me having to log in to my application. Is it possible on angular?

Comment: yeah just use `setInterval` on load of your root component.

Comment: Create a node server and deploy it using `firebase deploy` after you've init:ed a Firebase project in your project. Then you can write some logic which calls it at 9:41 am repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with Angular **reliably**. You want to schedule a cron job to run that firebase function. Take a look at [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) entry in their blog where they explain one way to do this.

---

*Edit*: `setInterval` approach. Should **not** be used unless unavoidable.

In theory, you could use `setInterval` to do this. But it would be finicky.

Say you have an Angular service, and a method. You call this service `CronService`. In your app component, you can call it, like this:

```
this.cronService.startScheduledJob();
```

Now the question is, when to call it.

You would need to trigger the function *once* at the exact time, 9:41 am. Say you have a button:

```
<button (click)="startMyJob()" [disabled]="isJobRunning">Start job</button>
```

Now, your component has this:

```
const ONE_DAY = 86400 * 1000; // one day has 86400 seconds, but we need milliseconds.

class Component {

  // Property to know if we started:
  isJobRunning = false;
  public startMyJob() {
    if (!this.isJobRunning) {
      this.isJobRunning = true;
    }
    // Now comes your interval part:
    setInterval(() => this.cronService.startScheduledJob(), ONE_DAY);
  }
```

Comment: this solution workks if the user doesn' t connect to angular-app ?

Comment: Nope. You do need a tab open _and active_.

Answer (score 2):

No - angular works on frontend - so only when user go to your page in the browser (however he not need to log in). You need do it on server

Comment: @Pardeep Jain Said to use setinterval. It is not possible ?

Comment: setInterwal will works only when user has open your angular page in browser.

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski no bro, I dont think so, Even your page is opened and user is not interacting `setinterval` should be called

Comment: @PardeepJain I agree with you - the angular page must be opened in a browser. I assume that OP dont want to open his angular page every day.

Comment: YES, but you can set the code like this too whenever after `9:41` user come your function will fire

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using / extending built in Angular's service worker.

Links stated at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44779032/browser-support-for-service-worker-task-scheduler) may be also useful:

- [Task Scheduler API Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/task-scheduler/)
- [Budget API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/budget-api)
- [Background Fetch](https://github.com/WICG/background-fetch)
- [Background Sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync)

Comment: This is interesting however: is this works when (at 9:41):
1. User has open browser but not open angular app?
2. User has closed browser?
3. User computer is turn off?

Comment: I did not test it by my self, sorry. (just gave you some theory). My guesses are: 1) YES, 2) I think - YES, 3) I think - NO